# Selenium search for element, delete the element then verify that the element is deleted

Tags: python, selenium

I have the functions below, where I wanna search for the element, if element found i wanna delete it then search for it again. Please see my code below:

1) This code verifies the text present.

```
 def verifyText(self, text):
            try:
                self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
                self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
                try:
                    self.text.find_element_by_xpath('//td[text() = "%s"]' % text)
                except:
                    self.text.find_element_by_xpath('//td/span[text() = "%s"]' % text)
            except:
                try:
                    self.text.find_element_by_xpath('//td[text() = "%s"]' % text)
                except:
                    self.text.find_element_by_xpath('//td/span[text() = "%s"]' % text)
```

2) This one deletes the element found

```
def deleteElement(self, text):
    driver.find_element_by_id("deletebutton").click()
    alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
```

3) Then i have a function written just to see if the element was deleted. I did not wanted to write the verify text function again so I used this. Is this a correct way to write it?

```
def verifyElement(self, text):
        if verifyText:
            raise Exception("Element could not be deleted")
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write your `verifyText()` as below:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def verifyText(self, text):
        try:
            self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
            self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
        except:
            pass  # Just do nothing if switching to frame failed. I suppose that if it's not in frame, then it's in the main body
        try:
            return self.text.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="%s"]' % text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False  # if element with specified text is not found
```

Note that `//td[.="%s"]` match both `//td[text()="%s"]` and `//td/span[text()="%s"]`

And then you can use it in `verifyElement()`:

```
def verifyElement(self, text):
    if self.verifyText(text):
        raise Exception("Element could not be deleted")
    # no need to use "else: pass"
```